# wp_trash_post function to only apply to posts, not pages!

Tags: functions

I have the following function that deducts at point when a post is removed. But when I remove a page, the wp_trash_post is also called.

```
// Remove 1 point if their post get removed
function deletePointFromUser($post_id) {
$post = get_post($post_id);
$authorid = $post->post_author;
$currentQPointNumber = get_user_meta($authorid, 'points', true);
// Delete 1 to the current Point Score
update_user_meta($authorid, 'points', $currentQPointNumber-1); 
 }
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'deletePointFromUser');
```

Is there a way to restrict this function to only apply to posts and not pages?

Comment: After the get_post line, why not just do a check for $post->post_type === 'post', and if not, just return?

Comment: @Shane : post that as an answer, please, and provide the modified code.

Comment: post_type doesnt work here

Comment: I don't see why 'post_type' doesn't work here.  dkl uses get_post() which will grab 'post_type' attribute from the post.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: Looks like Douglas.Sesar beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add something like:

```
// Remove 1 point if their post get removed
function deletePointFromUser($post_id) {
  $post = get_post($post_id);

  if( $post->post_type != 'post' ) return;//added code

  $authorid = $post->post_author;
  $currentQPointNumber = get_user_meta($authorid, 'points', true);
  // Delete 1 to the current Point Score
  update_user_meta($authorid, 'points', $currentQPointNumber-1); 
}
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'deletePointFromUser');
```

Then your point subtraction will only occur if the `$post` is a post.